# BASH: Printing the total number of unique elements in a tab delimited file

Tags: bash

my file

```
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value3   Something   SomeMore
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value3   Something   SomeMore
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value4   Something   SomeMore  
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value5   Something   SomeMore
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value6   Something   SomeMore
01  01   A   Value1   Value2   Value6   Something   SomeMore
...[more1000 similar lines]
```

So how do I extract the 6th column of the tab separated file and print the total number of unique values??

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to SO, always try to post sample of input and output in your post in CODE TAGS. Also try to put your efforts in your post too as we all are here to learn, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @Vaibhavi Ananthakrishnan, could you please do let us know if you need 6th column's unique values only here?

Comment: `cut -f 6 myFile | sort -u | wc -l` will do it. There are better ways, but that one is quick, simple, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '!a[$6]++{count++};END{print count}'  Input_file
```

Use `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}` for TAB delimited Input_file too.

***Solution 2nd:*** In GNU `awk` with length of array.

```
awk '{!a[$6]++} END{print length(a)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows on both the solutions:

```
awk '!a[$6]++{count++};END{print count}' Input_file
4
***********
awk '{!a[$6]++} END{print length(a)}' Input_file
4
```

Comment: @diginoise, It is working fine for me, I am getting `4` output in both the codes, please do let me know how it is not working for you?